# Find and Replace in Notepad++ using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I got a numeric list. One number per line. I want to replace all numbers with a specific pattern.
For example, my file look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to replace it so as to look like the following using a regexp in Notepad++:

```
[1],
[2],
[3],
....
```

Comment: Of course. But I could not caught regexp return value. How can I catch? is index number using $1?..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find what:

```
([0-9]+)
```

Replace with:

```
[\1],
```

Comment: Thanks. But Should I write regexp in ( )

Comment: You could also drop the `()` and use `[\0],` instead.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Nice one, didn't think of that :)