# how to use regular expression for notepad++ for $1

Tags: regex, notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find and Replace in Notepad++ using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840897/find-and-replace-in-notepad-using-regular-expression)

how to use regular expression for notepad++ for $1
when i use php ,I usually write it like this:
preg_replace("@aa(.*)bb@",$1,$str), but $1 is not wooking in notepad++
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `\1`, which is also very common.

```
@import "\1";
```

See also: [Understanding RegEx with Notepad++](http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the [current Notepad++ version](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.2.html).

**Since [Version 6.0 Notepad++ is supporting PCRE](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html), which is a great improvement and there you can also use `$1` in the replacement string.**

In the older versions you have to use `\1` to get the content of the first capturing group.